# Linq To Objects C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I want to get a collection of Bonds and their associate collection of maturities where the maturity.matamount > 200000.

edit:(I only want the maturity collection of each bond to include maturities > 200000)

Here is a program.cs that has the class defs and a method to populate test data for the query.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LinqToObjects
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program.QueryCollection();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void QueryCollection()
    {
        List<Bond> bonds = Program.BuildCollections();
        //how do I get a list of Bonds that have a maturity.MatAmount > 200,000?
    }
    public static List<Bond> BuildCollections()
    {
        List<Bond> bonds = new List<Bond>();
        Bond bond;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            bond = new Bond() {ID = i, Title = "Bond Title " + i.ToString() };
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
            { 
                bond.Maturities.Add(new Maturity(){ID = j, BondID = i, MatDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(j), MatAmount = 152000 * j});
            }

            bonds.Add(bond);
        }
        return bonds;
    }
}
public class Bond
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Maturity>  Maturities { get; set; }
    public Bond()
    {
        Maturities = new List<Maturity>();
    }
}
public class Maturity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int BondID { get; set; }
    public DateTime MatDate { get; set; }
    public int MatAmount { get; set; }
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  Is something not working?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
IEnumerable<Bond> bigBonds = bonds.Where(b => b.Maturities.Any(m => m.MatAmount > 200000));
```

Comment: wow this solution kicks mines' ass. This is definitely the simplest way to go. I'm not sure if performance is better, but this is very easy to understand and use (if you are unclear on => look up lambda functions).

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson Glad you like it :-) LINQ can sometimes get out of hand, but I think it works well in this case.

Comment: Matthew, thanks for that concise line of code.  I wonder if you can tweek your code to only return bonds with mats > 200k, but the collection of maturities should only have those maturities > 200k.  I am filtering on these maturities and it doesn't make since to include "all maturities".

Comment: If you want to do it this way, I recommend creating a delegate method rather than a lambda function. Try something like this:
`
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        IEnumerable<Bond> bigBonds = bonds.Where(FilterFunc);
    }

    private bool FilterFunc(Bond b)
    {
        bool result = false;

        List<Maturity> filteredMaturities = b.Maturities.Where(m => .MatAmount > 200000).ToList();
        if (filteredMaturities.Count > 0)
        {
             b.Maturities = filteredMaturities;
             result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
`

Comment: Just note that the above code will alter your original bond objects. You might want to clone the list before you call it. A way around that would be to drop the "Where" on the bonds and use a function to create new Bond objects using the originals as a base, and then do a "Where" on the original bonds' maturities.

Comment: @Terrence You can do this instead: `IEnumerable<Maturity> bigMaturities = bonds.SelectMany(b => b.Maturities.Where(m => m.MatAmount > 200000));`. But as @BenjaminDangerJohnson said in his answer, you're probably better off decoupling bonds from maturities if you want to work with them separately like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for but to get your bonds just do something like this:

```
var filteredBonds = 
        (
            from bond in bonds
            join maturity in maturities on bond.ID equals maturity.BondID
            where maturity.MatAmount > 200000
            select new { bond.ID, bond.Title, maturity.MatAmount, maturity.MatDate }
        ).ToList();
```

The ToArray() is optional, you could leave things in the table form if you like. I'm not really sure what you want to do with your results.

You might also want to decouple your Bonds and Maturities in your data structure. I don't think you really need to have a list of Maturities is you are storing the BondID as a member of a maturity object. It seems a little redundant, but honestly I don't use Linq so maybe that is the way to go. Your call.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I do like Matt's for is brevity.  Could you look at my follow up question to Matt?

Comment: I have been considering pulling the collection out of the bond.

Comment: If you do it this way, you will get only the bonds and maturities that exceed the proper value. But note that they will not be in the Bond/Maturity class format, they will be stored as DataRows (which is helpful if you want to consider switching to a database.)